# ValueError: could not convert string to float <ipython-input-5-1a15d1ec0505> in <module>()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to implement KNN but when i transform X_train and X_test it gives error, I am new please any help regarding this.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

It gives error "could not convert string to float"
what to do?

Comment: Where does it give the error? Can you show the whole error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I do when I see an error like this is to check my inputs. If you're getting a "could not convert string to float" error, you probably have a non-numeric string somewhere in your inputs (because it looks like this KNN function only takes numbers as input).

I'm assuming X_train and X_test are dataframes--try running the following for each column in your dataframe:

```
for i in range(len(X_train.columns)): 
    try:
        [float(j) for j in X_train[X_train.columns[i]]]
        print(X_train.columns[i],' is all-numeric')
    except:
        pass
```

Whichever column doesn't print when you run this is the one you need to look at and see if you can clean up the non-numeric entries in that column.

Edit: if you have a column of only non-numeric strings (for example, "Iris-setosa","Iris-versicolor", etc), you will have to convert them into numbers or Dummy Variable columns for the purposes of the KNN function.

Edit 2: Whoooops. I wrote bad code. Fixed it.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-11-db77ad8811b9>", line 4
    print(X_train.columns[i],' is all-numeric')
                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Thank you :) It was of great help

Comment: Glad I could help!